# How to inset a face without artifacts

Tags: modeling

I'd like to make a inset of a face, to get a similar result as the Photoshop's outline (but in 3D).

[image]

The final result I'm looking is something like:

[image]

I achieved this by insetting the top face and then extruding it. I'd like to have the "white/lower" part thicker.

But when I try a inset with higher thickness I get those artifacts:

[image]

How can I avoid this problem and get a flawless form?

Comment: that looks like you have overlapping geometry.  have you tried merge by distance to get rid of any duplicated vertices?

Answer (score 4):

You can't always avoid overlapping faces when you inset or extrude along normals, etc, you could just correct your topology, but it will work fine with a simpler topology:

[image]

[image]

[image]

You could also try the opposite, begin with the inner shape and extrude the faces along normals outward (enable the *Offset Even* option):

[image]

[image]

Give some topology corrections to avoid overlapping:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

After the operation, you can use the *Adjust Last Operation* panel to change a few options that may get you what you want.  Look at *Offset Even*, *Offset Relative*, and *Edge Rail*.

Default:

[image]

Uncheck *Offset Even*:

[image]

Check *Offset Relative*:

[image]

Check *Edge Rail*:

[image]

Different combinations of these will give different results.